# How to define c3p0 properties in the application.properties file of Spring

Tags: java, spring-data, c3p0

I want to define c3p0 properties in the application.properties file. But c3p0 properties seem not to be recognised. What goes wrong? Is there an example of an application.properties file with c3p0 settings?

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
c3p0.properties.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
c3p0.properties.url=jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}?autoReconnect=true
c3p0.properties.username=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
c3p0.properties.password=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}
c3p0.properties.acquire_increment=1
c3p0.properties.idle_test_period
c3p0.properties.timeout=14400
c3p0.properties.max_size=20
c3p0.properties.max_statements=50
c3p0.properties.min_size=3
```

Comment: What you mean by "c3p0 properties seem not to be recognised". You can't get those properties in your application?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It seems that is application does not take the parameters as input.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone is still interested...

It doesn't work with application.properties. Adding c3p0.properties file works.

Example of c3p0.properties:

```
c3p0.maxStatements=50
c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=3000
```

And in application.properties you need to specify data source type you want to use:

```
spring.datasource.type=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try

```
spring.jpa.properties.*
```

just like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 5
```

I found here [28. Working with SQL databases](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) in section 28.3.3 Creating and dropping JPA databases